# Codeigniter query - selecting a user by session ID and Logkey

Tags: php, codeigniter

Complete noob to Codeigniter (although I've been a developer for years), perhaps there's something I'm missing. I simply am unable to get this query working. No errors, no warnings/notices etc...

Why does this function not work? From what I'm reading in the CI manual for queries, this *seems* to be correct.

Any insight on this friends?

```
public function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->db->select('id, first_name, last_name, email, password, logkey');
        $this->CI->db->from('jive_users');
        $this->CI->db->where('id', $this->CI->session->id);
        $this->CI->db->where('logkey', $this->CI->session->logkey);
        $result = $this->CI->db->get();
        if($result->num_rows == 1){
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->first_name = $first_name;
            $this->last_name = $last_name;
            $this->email = $email;
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->logkey = $logkey;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You already found that `num_rows()` is *not property* but a __method__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to set variables which you did not define

```
$this->id = $id;
```

`$id` is not defined anywhere in your constructor

You can do something like this:

```
$row = $result->row();
$this->id = $row->id;
```

You may look into the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html)

As found out inside the comments, `$result->num_rows` also needs parentheses.

Comment: Ahh, I see your point. It's currently 3:31 in the AM haha so forgive me. However, that does not work.

Comment: @JasonBassett 'it does not work' is bad error description.

Comment: @JasonBassett Have you checked if $result->num_rows is 1? else there may be no database entry with the specified id and logkey

Comment: There is most certainly an entry with that information. I've even manually inputed the data as opposed to called the session data into the query and it still returns nothing.

Comment: I've found the issue... how ridiculous. 

I didn't add the parentheses after num_rows...

Comment: However your answer did help.

Comment: @JasonBassett I've edit my answer to add this. Also you shouldn't edit you question to fix this, cause it changes the issue. (: